# How can I use two component with map in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to use two component Text and Radiobutton with map. 
Like this..

please help me!

```
{Object.keys(temp_data).map(room => (
       <Text> {room} </Text>

        <RadioForm
         radio_props={radio_props}
         initial={0}
         buttonColor={'#2196f3'}
         animation={true}
         onPress={(value) => {this.setState({value:value})}}
        />

        ))
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fragment`

```js
{Object.keys(temp_data).map(room => (
       <React.Fragment>
         <Text> {room} </Text>
         <RadioForm
         radio_props={radio_props}
         initial={0}
         buttonColor={'#2196f3'}
         animation={true}
         onPress={(value) => {this.setState({value:value})}}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
     ))
   }
```

or

```js
{Object.keys(temp_data).map(room => (
       <>
         <Text> {room} </Text>
         <RadioForm
         radio_props={radio_props}
         initial={0}
         buttonColor={'#2196f3'}
         animation={true}
         onPress={(value) => {this.setState({value:value})}}
        />
      </>
     ))
   }
```

I think this way more cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap them in a `View`

```
{Object.keys(temp_data).map(room => (
       <View>
         <Text> {room} </Text>
         <RadioForm
         radio_props={radio_props}
         initial={0}
         buttonColor={'#2196f3'}
         animation={true}
         onPress={(value) => {this.setState({value:value})}}
        />
      </View>
     ))
   }
```